# $state.go leads me to the otherwise statement and does not transition to the right state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to move into the menu.home state but when I do `$state.go('menu.home)` it does not do anything and it goes into the otherwise statement.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

**Controller.js**

```
$state.go('menu.home');
```

**routes.js**

```
angular.module('app.routes', [])    
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {



// Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider

  .state('login', {
     cache: false,
     url:'/login',
     templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
     controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  })  

  .state('menu.home', {
     cache: false,
     url: '/home',
     views: {
       'side-menu21': {
         templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
         controller: 'MapCtrl' //'homeCtrl'
       }
     }
  })

  .state('menu.cart', {
     url: '/page2',
     views: {
       'side-menu21': {
         templateUrl: 'templates/cart.html',
         controller: 'cartCtrl'
       }
     }
  })

  .state('menu.cloud', {
     url: '/page3',
     views: {
       'side-menu21': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/cloud.html',
          controller: 'cloudCtrl'
        }
     }
  })

  .state('menu.test', {
    cache: false,
    url: '/test',
    views: {
      'side-menu21': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/test.html',
        controller: 'testCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('menu', {
    url: '/side-menu21',
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    abstract: true
  })

//$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login')
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location) {
  console.log("Could not find: " + JSON.stringify($location));
  $location.path('/login');
})



});
```

every time I try to do `$state.go('menu.home')` this is the output i get:

```
 Could not find:     {"$$protocol":"http","$$host":"localhost","$$port":8100,"$$path":"/app/sear    ch","$$search":    {},"$$hash":"","$$url":"/app/search","$$absUrl":"http://localhost:8100/#/ap   p/search","$$state":null,"$$replace":false}
```

**login.html**

```
     <ion-view view-title="Login" id="login" name="login-view">
       <ion-content class="padding">

    <!--##########################Facebook Login#################################-->
    <div class="facebookLogin">
    <a class="facebook-sign-in button button-royal" ng-click="facebookSignIn()">Login with Facebook</a>
    </div>
    <!--#######################END Facebook Login#################################-->

          <div class="list list-inset">

              <label class="item item-input">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="data.username">
              </label>

              <

    label class="item item-input">
                  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="data.password">
              </label>

          </div>
      <button class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="login()">Login</button>


  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

home.html

```
    <ion-view title="Test" id="home" class=" ">

    <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header"></ion-content>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MapCtrl">
    <!-- Google Maps -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <ion-content scroll="false">
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        <!-- END GOOGLE MAPS!-->

     <!-- Test button 
    <div class="TestButton">
    <div class="button button-assertive" ng-click="Test()" ng-hide="hideTestButton">
      <a class="button">Test</a>
    </div>

    </div>


    End Request Test button----------->



<!-- OS/Production selection footer-->

      <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top">
      <ion-tab title="Apple" icon-off="ion-social-apple" icon-on="ion-social-apple" href="#/app/search" on-select="appleTab()">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-search"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <ion-tab title="Windows" icon-off="ion-social-windows" icon-on="ion-social-windows" href="#/app/browse" on-select="windowsTab()">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-browse"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <ion-tab title="Mobile" icon-off="ion-iphone" icon-on="ion-iphone" href="#/app/playlists" on-select="mobileTab()">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-playlists"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>
      <ion-tab title="Network" icon-off="ion-wifi" icon-on="ion-wifi"" href="#/app/playlists" on-select="otherTab()">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-playlists"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

    </ion-tabs>
</ion-content>
</body>
</ion-view>
```

If I comment out : `$location.path('/login');` then it works. Not sure why this happens, Please help!

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `icon-on="ion-wifi""` should be `icon-on="ion-wifi"`

Comment: Thanks for catching that, just fixed it! but still not getting the states to transition

Comment: I believe you need a base state of `menu` when you using dot notation. I don't have the time to verify and add an answer so just want to throw this in a comment.

Comment: but i do, the last state is the base menu state

Comment: That's what I get for trying to answer questions when I don't have the time read the question properly.. sorry! I don't see `<div ui-view></div>` in your home.html template for the nested states to get inserted.

Comment: haha its alright!  I just added that still not getting the state to transition

Comment: This is weird, I am able to transition into menu.test

Comment: If I look at $stateProvider in the routes.js it is blank ({ }) for some reason when I do $state.go('menu.home')

Comment: If I comment out : $location.path('/login'); then it works. Not sure why this happens, Please help!

Comment: you didnt include ui.router as your dependency

Comment: @Sherlock I added ionic as my dependency.  I tried adding ui.router as a dependency but it did not do anything

Answer (score 0):

Is that all that is in your controller.js file? Maybe there is something in there that is preventing hitting that state. Make sure in your main html file you have `<main ui-view></main>` to establish all your routes.

Comment: no here is more of my controller    .controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $q, sessionService, $ionicLoading, $timeout, $log, $http, $ionicPopup, $location) {
    
        isRealDevice = ionic.Platform.isWebView();
        $scope.data = {};


        $scope.login = function () {
$state.go('menu.home');                                                                                                                             }

Comment: Okay, try this. `.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $q, sessionService, $ionicLoading, $timeout, $log, $http, $ionicPopup, $location, $rootScope) {
       $rootScope.$state = $state 
       isRealDevice = ionic.Platform.isWebView(); 
       $scope.data = {}; 
       $scope.login = function () { 
         $state.go('menu.home'); 
       } `

Comment: Still same results, its not transitioning to the other state.  Not sure why it only has issues resolving menu.home all the other routes work fine

Comment: It is hard not seeing the rest of your application. Perhaps a plunkr would be appropriate. You can always hit the state from the html too. Instead of ` <button class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="login()">Login</button>` Try `<a ui-sref="menu.home"><button class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="login()">Login</button></a>`

Comment: I tried that still nothing.  Is there a specific part of the application you want to see?

Comment: Not sure if this will help but for some reason when I do $state.go('menu.home')  its redirecting me to /app/search  Not sure where its getting that from

Comment: This might be why `<ion-tab title="Apple" icon-off="ion-social-apple" icon-on="ion-social-apple" href="#/app/search" on-select="appleTab()">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-search"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>` remove the href

Answer (score 0):

Got it, so it does not like the href that i have in my ion-tabs in the home.html.  It might be trying to resolve them which are not point to valid urls.  Once I removed the href it worked perfectly fine.  Thanks for all the help everyone!